# How to replace switch statement of expressions

Tags: c#

I have some code switching based on the enum value passed to it which then performs a database query (via EF)

```
switch(regtype)
{
    case RegType.Type1:
        return (Dc.ListPeople(n => n.RegistrationType1Id != null)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Max(n => n.RegistrationType1Id ) ?? 0) + 1;
    case RegType.Type2:
        return (Dc.ListPeople(n => n.RegistrationType2Id != null)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Max(n => n.RegistrationType2Id ) ?? 0) + 1;
...
}
```

Now the data model is what it is, let's look past that. `RegistrationType_N_Id` is an `int?`, `ListPeople` takes an argument of `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`.

There are a total of 3 enum values, so it's not *that* bad, but even just for the mental exercise, I'd like to know if I could replace this switch statement with something more fancy.

I thought of a `Dictionary<RegType, Expression<Func<something>>>`, but since the first use in the db predicate is different from the 2nd in `Max()` got me stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate method that will take the property selector as  parameter. Entity Framework cannot deal directly with delegates, since it has to translate your code into SQL, so it is necessary to deal with expression trees.

```
public int M(Expression<Func<Person, int?>> selector)
{
    var expr = Expression.NotEqual(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(expr, selector.Parameters);

    return (Dc.ListPeople(lambda)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Max(selector)) ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
switch(regtype)
{
    case RegType.Type1:
        return M(x => x.RegistrationType1Id);
```

Comment: This throws a "NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." EF needs an `Expression<Func>` to create the appropriate SQL query as far as I know.

Comment: @romeozor I missed the EF part. I changed `Func` to `Expression<Func>` in the method declaration.

Comment: but now the code is trying to invoke an expression, that won't compile

Comment: @romeozor It looks like you'll need to use expresion trees. Can you please take a look at the current code?

Comment: I think the new expression in the Max() is redundant as it's re-creating the one passed as method argument, but otherwise cool.